# Transferring Azure Virtual Machine blob

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download the Azure VM blob by using the Azure Storage Explorer so that I could upload the .vhd to another subscription. However, I got this error "**Unable to read data from the transportation connection:The connection was closed.**" when downloading the blob.

Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

In order to transfer VHD from one storage account to another, you don't need to do that. In fact, I will go out on a limb and say "**Please Stop Using Azure Storage Explorer**". This tool has not been updated in ages and does not have the latest functionality offered by Azure Storage.

Azure Storage supports Async Server Side copy blob which will copy the blobs from one storage account to another on the server side without having to download the blob first from source storage account and reupload it in target storage account.

I would recommend using [`AzCopy`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/04/01/azcopy-using-cross-account-copy-blob.aspx) which is now part of Azure SDK. If you've the latest version of SDK installed on your computer, you can find it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\AzCopy` folder. Here's the sample usage to copy file from one storage account to another:

```
AzCopy "https://<oldaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<oldaccountcontainername .. usually vhds>/" "https://<newaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<newaccountcontainername .. again vhds>/" "<filenametocopy.extension"  /SourceKey:<oldaccountkey> /DestKey:<newaccountkey> /BlobType:page /S
```

Comment: Hi, would you mind giving me an example for oldaccountname and oldaccountcontainername? I mean where can I find it?

Comment: This is the account name and container name from where you're downloading the blob using Azure Storage Explorer.

Comment: And for the account key, is it the one that we can get from "manage access keys"?

Comment: Means that when I downloading the blob, the filename appears to be ABC-ALICE, the "ABC" will be the account name while the container name will be "ALICE"?

Comment: It would be hard to tell me this way. Will it possible for you to take a screenshot of Azure Storage Explorer and post that in your question above or upload it somewhere and share the link. I should be able to tell you then.

Comment: :) ... you masked everything ... but let me try ... So the account name is the one selected in top left dropdown just before "Add Account" button. Container is the "vhds" and I can't really tell the blob name as you have masked it.

Comment: I have replaced a new one. Can you please check. Thank you~~

Comment: Thanks. So the account name is "portalvhds30shpvsy...", container name is "vhds". The filename is the name you see in the right hand pane. HTH.

Comment: Can I know how can I solve this error that I got when using azcopy. The sourcekey is not in base-64 string.

Comment: This error usually means you're providing an incorrect account key. Just use the account key when you connected to storage account in Azure Storage Explorer.